# include STL header file inside a function C++14

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

tl;dr: Can I somehow make this code work in C++14 (GCC 6.3)?

```
int main(){
    #include<vector>
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

But code below works just fine!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    #include<cstdio>
    using namespace __gnu_cxx;
    printf("Hello world\n.");
    return 0;
}
```

Using C++14 (gcc-6.3) code doesn't compile with error message being

```
 error: 'namespace' definition is not allowed here
 namespace std
 ^~~~~~~~~
```

> Why I want to do this?
>
> I don't have access outside of the function where I am allowed to code. I can't #include in global area.

UPD: Changing to cstdlib also works problem is not exclusion by header guard (according to me) but namespace problem. Because C++ header files have namespace std, while c header files doesn't. I wanted to ask whether there is some tweak for namespace issue?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do this?

Comment: "*I don't have access outside of the function where I am allowed to code.*" Ask for access.

Comment: If it's a school assigment, don't do that, it will be rejected anyway

Comment: @krisz There are some tasks in online judges where you are asked to do a task which can be very easily solved by library functions. For example: to write "merge" function, it's trivial! No, it's not school assignment as per your concern.

Comment: So you do online judges as a hobby or to learn and yet you want to cheat. If you just solved it without a vector you would have already be done.

Comment: @madhur4127 why don't you just search for the implementation of that function and add something like that in your code? Those rules are clearly set in place so you can't just solve the task by using a library function. Yes, I know, someone asking you to reinvent the wheel sucks, but if that's the case and you have to do it, you have to do it.

Comment: @krisz real problem is adjacency list. How do make them? Using array of pointer to linked list? Because it is waste of time in implementing as opposed to learning. 30 line of code suddenly bloats to 200!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I somehow make this code work

No. Standard headers (and most library headers in general)  must be included in the global namespace scope.

> But code below works just fine!

But it's not guaranteed to work. It just happened to work, probably because `<iostream>` had already included `<cstdio>` and so your own inclusion was removed by header guards.

Comment: I think its not the case that header guard excluded it. I ran the code using cstdlib and iosteam and it compiled successfully. I dont believe functions like malloc, rand are included in iostream.

Comment: @madhur4127 why do you not believe that functions like malloc etc could be included by iostream? Then how do you explain this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5eab48bd6077701

Comment: I saw [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and it shows that malloc is part of cstdlib and there is [no function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) malloc in it. I still don't understand why doesn't the reference mention it or is it an extension by gcc compiler? Help!

Comment: @madhur4127 the reference doesn't mention it because iostream isn't required to include cstdlib. stdlibc++ (the GNU standard library implementation) simply has chosen to include it for whatever purposes it has to do so. Standard library headers are allowed to include other headers.